# Azure PowerShell Code to Loop across datasets in a pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I got below code to loop across datasets in a Azure datafactory

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "WikiADF"
```

However, I need to loop across datasets belonging to a specific pipeline.
Couldn't get hold of it.

Answer (score 1):

Datasets can be referenced from multiple pipelines within the same factory, so to find datasets referenced by a specific pipeline you'll need to analyze that pipeline itself.  Each pipeline has a list of activities, each of which has a list of inputs and outputs, each of which is a dataset reference.

Comment: I am aware about the datasets in pipeline but I was looking for an automated solution(Powershell ) to loop across the dataset names specific to a pipeline only.
PS: I don't want to *hard code* the dataset names in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Josephs comment above, here is the code.

```
#Put your Data Factory name and Resource group here and pipeline
$RG = "asdf"
$DFname = "asdfasdf"
$Pipeline = "CopyPipeline-sdfas"
#Once per session - comment out to save time
#Login-AzureRmAccount

# Once, select a default subscription for your current session
#Get-AzureRmSubscription
#Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId "asdfasdfasdfasdfasd"

# One time per computer - comment out to save time
# Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.DataFactory

# Debug option: List all DF in a resource group for debugging if needed
#Get-AzureRmDataFactory -ResourceGroupName $RG

# Find the Data Factory
$df= Get-AzureRmDataFactory -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $DFname
if ($df -eq $null) { Write-Host "Data Factory " $DFname " cannot be found. Check spelling and resource group name. Error: " $_ -BackgroundColor:Red }

$activities = (Get-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $Pipeline -DataFactoryName $DFname).Properties.Activities

$DataSets = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
ForEach($activity in $activities)
{
    ForEach($tempDS in $activity.Inputs) { 
        Write-Host "temp ds name: " + $tempDS.Name 
        $DataSets.Add($tempDS) 
    }
    ForEach($tempDS in $activity.Outputs) { 
        Write-Host "temp ds name output: " + $tempDS.Name 
        $DataSets.Add($tempDS) 
    }
    #ForEach($tempDS in $activity.Outputs) { $AllDataSetNames.Add($tempDS.Name) }
    #Write-Host "Input Activity: " + $activity.Inputs.ForEach('Name') 
    #Write-Host "Output Activity: " + $activity.Outputs.ForEach('Name') 
}

Write-Host "all datasets:"
$DataSets.ForEach('Name')
```

Comment: How can we do it for Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline